# STACKED DIAGNOSTICS in redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, exception, amazon-redshift, plpgsql

I was trying to use STACKED DIAGNOSTICS in redshift for error handling. But it's giving errors. Is there any equivalent of postgresql's STACKED DIAGNOSTICS for redshift?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please Edit your question to provide more information, such as what you have tried and what specific problems you are experiencing. For tips on asking a good question, please see: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Probably not - redshift is based on very old Postgres without modernizations.